# Joining two pdfs with slightly different page size with pdfjoin

Tags: pdf, merge

I'm trying to merge multiple PDF files by using `pdfjoin`. However the joined PDF is not right beacuse orientation for some text is changed. I have checked all options of `pdfjoin`, enforcing orientation etc. but of no use.

The two source PDFs have slightly different dimensions (595 × 842, 595 × 841) and should be merged as A4. How can I merge them in A4?

I know about other merging tools online but the problem with them is that the generated PDF is not further processable as in `pdfjoin`.

I'd like to know if there are some solutions to merge PDFs with slightly different sizes in to a single file using `pdfjoin`.

Answer (score 23):

```
pdfjoin --paper a4paper --rotateoversize false
```

does the trick for me. rotateoversize is the important option

Answer (score 2):

`pdfjam --paper a4paper file1.pdf file2.pdf` did the trick for me using one letter-sized document and one slightly-not-A4-document, they're both joined as A4 as expected.

Comment: Comment by the OP: Thanks but I found a solution for pdfjoin as well. There is an option --rotateoversize which rotate a page that has even a slightly large page size. By setting it to false, it fixed the problem.

Comment: pdfjoin is just a front end for pdfjam, you can use all pdfjam options with pdfjoin