# To pdfjoin without rotation and addition of white space

Tags: linux, pdf

I have 4 scanned documents which contains 3x3 pictures.
I run in the folder of files

```
pdfjoin *
```

I get some pages automatically rotated such that much white space around.
This is annoying.

All pages in 4 files are in the right rotation.
Documents should only by joined together without changing their rotation or adding white space.

How can you do pure pdfjoin without rotation and addition of white space?

### Differential solution used nowadays by OP

LaTeX because you can automate but some work still in process for 5% of pictures, see the thread [How to rotate image 90 if height overful?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341553/13173) where you just loop through the images and adjust them to the document; you can also do there cropping, captions etc - - which works much better than any combination of terminal approaches with `pdfjoin`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Joining two pdfs with slightly different page size with pdfjoin](https://superuser.com/questions/352795/joining-two-pdfs-with-slightly-different-page-size-with-pdfjoin-under-linux-or-m/799627#799627)

```
pdfjoin --paper a4paper --rotateoversize false
```

does the trick for me. rotateoversize is the important option

Comment: Important indeed but not even documented. Thank you!